# Azure Key Vault Physical HSM

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am referring the document below:

[How to generate and transfer HSM-protected keys for Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-hsm-protected-keys/#prerequisites-for-byok//)

One of the prerequisite is:

Thales HSM, smartcards, and support software

My question is do I really need to buy a physical HSM to generate key using HSM?

Comment: That very likely depends on your use case! what do you want to use it for...

Comment: We just want to generate a key that never get out of HSM boundary.

Comment: @Alvin Was my answer what you were looking for or did I not understand your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you do not need to buy an HSM to have an HSM generated key.  The Key Vault API exposes an option for you to create a key.  The key creation happens inside the HSM.  From the Documentation:

> Create: Allows a client to create a key in Azure Key Vault. The value
>   of the key is generated by Azure Key Vault and stored and is not
>   released to the client. Asymmetric (and in the future, Elliptic Curve
>   and Symmetric) keys may be created in Azure Key Vault.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn903623.aspx#BKMK_KeyOperations